# How to insert HTML form input into API object array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I have two code "snippets" that I would like to combine but I don't really know how to.

I've managed to make HTML form input into an JSON object. See codepen [here](https://codepen.io/erikwaahlstrom/pen/eedrGX).

When I click the "Add note" btn I want to grab the input values -> make them to an object -> POST them to my api object array. Image and code example below:

HTML to JSON
[image]

```
// CREATE NEW NOTES
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('POST', 'https://timesheet-1172.appspot.com/af25fa69/notes');

request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

request.onload = function () {

    // When I click the "Add note" btn I want to grab the input values -> make them to an object -> POST them to my api object array.

    // Like

    // var body = {
    //  'title': form.title.value,
    //  'description': form.description.value
    // }

};

request.send(JSON.stringify(body));

});
```

This is the current code that I have which let's me send an already set variable with object properties. See image below:

SEND JSON
[image]

However my question is regarding how i can combine these tho examples so I can make dynamic inputs -> convert them to a JSON object -> Insert them in the api object array.

Feel free to correct me if you think that i'm on the wrong path or if you think have a solution!

If you have any questions or need clarification don't hesitate to ask!

Thanks beforehand!

// E

Comment: It looks as though you've got everything you need already. Have you tried just taking the above code, and placing it within what you've got on CodePen? Could you clarify a bit more?

Comment: The codepen code is the first "snippet" that saves the input as an object and the second pasted code is the "snippet" that sends the code to the API. However I can't seem to combine the two code snippets. (Save input to html file and send to API). I want the codepen code to be inside the onload function and POST the new object to my API object array. Haha I hope that explains it better, otherwise ask! :) @Justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine them like this (and I think this is the best approach):

Define a function that will be executed on form submit, it will create JSON and send it via ajax:

```
function formatJSONAndSend(form) {
  var body = {
    title: form.title.value,
    description: form.description.value
  };

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('POST', 'https://timesheet-1172.appspot.com/af25fa69/notes');
  request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');    
  request.send(JSON.stringify(body));
}
```

And you can call it from your `HTML` like:

```
<form onsubmit="formatJSONAndSend(this);">
    Title: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Title goes here..." /><br /> Description: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" placeholder="Description goes here..." /><br />
    <input class="btn btn-primary" id="btn" type="submit" value="Add note">
</form>
```

After you submit your form by clicking on **Add note** button it will call the `formatJSONAndSend()` function which will first grab the data from the form and put it in `body` object which is then sent via `POST` to your web api.

Here's a working example: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NwRLKg)

Comment: Hmm this doesn't seem to work for me. Does it work for you? I will be testing it further tho. Thanks for your response! :) @Ante Jablan Adamović

Comment: I've added a working example it's a bit different but I've checked and it works ... `Codepen` might block your request so best to copy over `.html` and `.js` to your local machine and test there.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to get it to work now! @Ante Jablan Adamović